# Can assigning many basic data types cause memory leakage, and can you avoid it?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

Say I have a program like this:

```
int main(void) {
    while(1) {
        int some_int = rand(); //Some randomly generated integer
        printf("%d\n", some_int);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The program spins in an infinite loop, declaring `some_int` in every iteration. I am aware that if you allocate some memory you should free it at a later stage to avoid memory leakage in a program, and to my knowledge there is no garbage collector in C to free memory that unused variables. Does this mean that my current implementation causes memory leaking since I declare a new integer that I only use once? Is there any way to "free" the memory it uses?

You could of course move the variable declaration outside of the infinite loop but this is only a theoretical case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local variable has *automatic storage duration*. Meaning that the compiler will automatically pick the best place to store it, and automatically clean up when the variable goes out of scope at `}`. In practice, the CPU will likely store the variable in a CPU register. So your code is fine.

The only time you need to `free` is when you use allocated storage, by explicitly calling malloc/calloc/realloc. Languages like Java with garbage collection use implicit heap allocation everywhere, behind the lines. C does not do this, which is one of many reasons why C is so much faster than Java by design.

Comment: (Nitpick in Java, only `java.lang.Object` types and arrays of primitives or `java.lang.Object`s are schedulable for garbage collection: i.e. anything created with `new`. But +1 anyway.)

Comment: I'd rather say that "Java is slower than C by design" instead of the other way round, by looking at their relative age ;)